# How can we use GCSObjectExistenceSensor to sense one or more files with filemask

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

How can we use GCSObjectExistenceSensor to sense one or more files with filemask which are present in a folder in GCS bucket.

when using **"use_glob"** getting invalid argument error.

I tried to sense files with first 4 letter of the filename and i am expecting to sense existense of one or more files.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the stack exchange community. In order for the community to help, you should provide code samples that you have tried and the error output you're facing. Don't hesitate to validate an answer if it solved your issue. Enjoy the website.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/sensors/gcs/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.gcs.GCSObjectsWithPrefixExistenceSensor)

> Checks for the existence of GCS objects at a given prefix, passing matches via XCom.

> When files matching the given prefix are found, the poke method’s criteria will be fulfilled and the matching objects will be returned from the operator and passed through XCom for downstream tasks.